# Wi-Fi issues when system is on for long time

Tags: networking, wireless

I am having a Lenovo 330-15ARRR with Ryzen processor. And running Ubuntu 18.10 in  it.

- At first i cannot get to on WiFi then i tried to install it with the help of forums, and also after trying many inputs i have got the WiFi. But now if i place the laptop in sleep mode for longer time my doesn't work until i reboot the system.
- Can anyone tell me why it is happening and also the process to avoid it?
- The output of commands are `uname -sr`

  ```
  Linux 4.18.0-11-generic
  ```
- For `sudo lshw -C network`

`*-network DISABLED

       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: b0:fc:36:75:fb:55
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ce latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
       resources: irq:54 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:e0800000-e080ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 8c:16:45:c7:8d:7c
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:49 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e0704000-e0704fff memory:e0700000-e0703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp3s0f3u3
       serial: 3a:d8:eb:26:50:79
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.112 link=yes multicast=yes`

- For `lspci`

  ```
  00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d0
  00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d1
  00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
  00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
  00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
  00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
  00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15db
  00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15dc
  00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
  00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
  00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e8
  00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e9
  00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ea
  00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15eb
  00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ec
  00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ed
  00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ee
  00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ef
  01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
  02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
  03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c4)
  03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15de
  03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15df
  03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e0
  03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e1
  03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e3
  04:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 61)
  ```
- For `rfkill list all`

  ```
  0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: yes
     Hard blocked: no
  1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: yes
     Hard blocked: no
  2: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: yes
     Hard blocked: no
  5: hci0: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: yes
     Hard blocked: no
  ```

Comment: rfkill unblock all, turn off sleep mode for the network and turn on auto retry

Answer (score 0):

I have LENOVO PC with a `RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`

The problem is solved like this:

---

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe -v 8821ce
```

---

### --> reboot